# SQL Server: Converting a number to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column which represent the values as seconds. The Result of this column are as (465109,352669,351949.... etc). I need the results to be always in decimals and less then one. So the 465109 result should come as 0.465109, Similarly the 352669 should come as 0.352669.

Is there a way i can do that in SQL Sever 2008?

```
DATEDIFF(SECOND,StartDate,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just use division?

```
select seconds / 1000000.0
```

Note the `.0` so it does floating point division rather than integer division.

If you want these as a decimal, then cast afterwards:

```
select cast(seconds / 1000000.0 as decimal(10, 6))
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon,, This was helpful

Answer (score 0):

A trick is this:

```
CAST('.' + REPLACE(CAST(@value AS varchar(30)), '.', '') AS Numeric(28,10))
```

And as a math solution:

```
CAST(@valueAS Numeric(28,10)) / (POWER(10, LEN(CAST(FLOOR(@value) AS varchar(20)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select @x = DATEDIFF(SECOND,StartDate,GETDATE());
select @x/power(10,len(@x));
```

You can try this by dividing with the length of integer returned by `datediff` function raised to the power of 10.